# FormEmailer Script Error Message

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using the FormEmailer script written by Henrique Abreu.
It is an amazing program & I am so glad to have found it.
I have one issue that has confounded me though. When I process the lines manually, it works perfectly, however, when I want to use the form submit trigger, I get an error message & it doesn’t work. This is the message:
onEdit  TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of undefined. (line 198) formSubmit
I am stumped, any help, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance, Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you setting/running it for the "form submit"? From your description it seems that you're trying to run it directly from the code editor, are you? If not, then this error message you're getting is on your email, right?

Anyway, the correct function to run is called `timeDriven`. And you should open the script editor, click the "Resources" menu and set the trigger to run it. When I wrote this version, there was no [concurrency support](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=202) or anyway to [get the row of the form submitted](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=128). Therefore the only safe solution we had was to use the time-driven trigger, which is what I recommend you to use. But if you form has somewhat low usage, i.e. it's unlikely that two or more users will submit data nearly simultaneously, then you can use the *on form submit* trigger.

By the way, I'm not sure Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions related to [FormEmailer](http://sites.google.com/site/formemailer), as it is really [meant only for programming](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) doubts. Well... unless you're modifying its code. FormEmailer related questions should be posted in its [Google Group](https://sites.google.com/site/formemailer/group).

Comment: Sorry, I will post my comment to the appropriate Google Group, as you recommended.

Comment: It's ok. I've just created the Group anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for responding to my request for help.

At first, I was running it from the form.

I got so discouraged, I deleted everything & started over.

I stopped getting error messages, so I don’t know what caused it in the first place, but it still didn’t work from formsubmit.

After reading your reply, I realized, I had the function set to “OnEdit”. I then changed it to “timeDriven”, as you said I should, and it seems to work perfectly.

Thank you so much for the advice, as well as for writing a wonderful script! I have seen many, but none work as well as this one.
Thanks, Michael